# Utility to hash and list files with identical contents?

Tags: windows, file, hash

UltraEdit saves temporary, ie. unsaved/untitled, files as (regex) "Edit.\d+".

When UltraEdit is killed (I do this when some software nags me to reboot), I noticed that it doesn't always save files in the same directory, so I end up with a bunch of "Edit.\d+" files scattered in my two hard-disks, with a lot of identical contents.

So I'd like a free utility for Windows that can...

1. search my hard-disks for all files whose filename matches "Edit.\d+"
2. generate some hashing of the file so it has some signature, and
3. output a list of all identical files so that I don't waste time checking files that exist in multiple copies on my hard-disk, and just take care of unique files.

Anyone knows of such a thing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found this: http://www.atory.com/Dupe_Checker/

can't give you a review but it looks legit